# Spring-Amqp and Apollo

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, apollo

I'm using the Spring-AMQP library with RabbitMQ for production. I wanted to write some tests that would work "cleanly" and I was thinking about using an embedded broker and mocking the responses. I know that I cannot embed Rabbit, but was wondering if Spring AMQP will work with Apollo, or another broker that will work in the JVM.

I am okay with only publishing and subscribing, and using vendor specific code for setting up queues if need be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; although there is a general abstraction (in the `spring-amqp` project), there currently is only a concrete implementation for RabbitMQ (`spring-rabbit`).

Since AMQP is a wire protocol, you might be able to use the rabbit client underneath Spring AMQP with some other broker, but only if it (the broker) supports the same protocol version. Apollo is AMQP 1.0 which is completely different to the version that RabbitMQ complies with (0-9-1).

For the framework itself, we use `Mockito` to mock the rabbit `amqp-client` where we can. For more complex tests where mocking is too hard, and for integration tests, we use a JUnit `@Rule` (`BrokerRunning`) to skip the tests if there's not a broker on `localhost`.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!